# Interactively remove files in loop with standard input redirection

Tags: bash, rm, input, stdin

I need to interactively (i.e. `rm -i`) remove files stored in variable `$to_remove` (one path per line). Unfortunately my code doesn't work because standard input is already used by redirection `<<< "$to_remove"`.

```
while read -r f ; do
    rm -ir "$f"
done <<< "$to_remove"
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Given that `find` is the source of the data, I would use an array instead:

```
readarray -t to_remove < <(find ...)
number_of_files=${#toremove[@]}
rm -i "${to_remove[@]}"
```

If you are a pre-4 version of `bash`, use this loop to fill the array.

```
while IFS= read -r fname; do
    to_remove+=("$fname")
done < <(find ...)
```

None of these work with with files that contain newlines, but I find that case easier to ignore when possible, although in `bash` 4, you can dispense with the call to `find` altogether:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
to_remove=( "$WORKING_PATH"/**/* )
```

---

I assume you're populating `to_remove` from a file. Don't do that; read directly from the file.

```
while IFS= read -r fname <&3; do
    rm -i "$fname"
done 3< file.txt
```

This also uses a separate file descriptor to read from the file so that standard input can be used by `rm`.

(If you are truly stuck reading from `to_remove`, I would just use a temporary file:

```
printf "%s" "$to_remove" > tmp.txt
while IFS= read -r fname <&3; do
    rm -i "$fname"
done 3< tmp.txt
rm tmp.txt
```

)

Comment: No. `$to_remove` is defined like this: `$to_remove=\`find $WORKING_PATH -empty -print\``. Afterwards `$to_remove` is processed. I save result of `find` in variable in order to **not** call `find` twice: `$to_remove=\`find $WORKING_PATH -empty -print\``. `$number_of_files=\`find $WORKING_PATH -empty -print | wc -l\``.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in `echo "$to_remove"` ; do
    rm -ir "$f"
done
```

Short version:

```
IFS=$'\n'
rm -ir "$to_remove"
```

Those two versions works as expected.

---

Strange enough the following code doesn't work:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in "$to_remove" ; do
    rm -ir "$f"
done
```

Why?

Comment: In the first example, the result of the command substitution undergoes word-splitting. In the second example, the quoted parameter expansion does not. Either way, you shouldn't be storing file names in a flat string parameter; it won't work if any of the file names contain newlines or other non-whitespace characters interpreted by the shell.